# Securing a flask app (python)

Tags: python, web-services, security, https, flask

I am trying to learn to write Flask apps and, in particular, how to secure them.  I have successfully implemented a log-ins using the 'http basic authentication' but it occurred to me that all of the information being sent back in response to the request isn't protected.
E.g. the following flask app returns some personal information

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'PERSONAL INFORMATION'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Could someone suggest the best way to secure the passing of the information back?  Are there multiple ways and if so what their advantages?  I know 'https' is secure but I'm guessing I cant just add an 's' to my request address!

Cheers,

Jack

Comment: You need to use https for protect sensible data.

Comment: Define sensible data?  Could you give a bit more information about if thats possible with flask/how to start?

Comment: Any private user data. You could just use Nginx to handle https connections. No need to change anything in your flask app.

Comment: @dizballanze: you probably meant to use the word *sensitive* there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you'd want to run your Flask app behind a reverse proxy like nginx with HTTPS enabled. There are a number of tutorials online about doing this.

If you're interested in securing your app beyond HTTP Basic Auth, you might be interested in [Flask-Security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/).

Answer (score 0):

I too was having issues with a non-secure app deployment. I was on an Eco Dyno but what you need is to upgrade to Basic.

Deploy with [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management) and...

> with Automated Certificate Management (ACM), Heroku automatically
> manages TLS certificates for apps with Basic and Professional dynos on
> the Common Runtime, and for apps in Private Spaces that enable the
> feature.